# Click listener of button inside a layout view that is bind with click listener is not working in Android

Tags: android, android-button

I am developing an Android app. In my app, I have a button inside a layout view. Layout view is set click listener. Button inside layout is also bind with click listener. But when I click button inside layout, both listeners are not working. But when I click layout view avoiding button, listener of layout view is working.

For example, this is my layout file

```
<LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/child_container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
         <Button
            android:focusable="false"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
            android:text="LIKE"
            android:id="@+id/btn_click"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

This is example of onCreate event of my activity

```
childContainer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                   //this is working
                                }
                            });

btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onClick(View v) {
                                    //This is not working
                                }
                            });
```

As you can see I set `android:focusable="false"` and `android:focusableInTouchMode="false"` to button in layout file. But click listener of button is not working. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

Remove these lines:

```
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
```

From docs:

[`android:focusable="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusable):

> Boolean that controls whether a view can take focus. By default the
>   user can not move focus to a view; by setting this attribute to true
>   the view is allowed to take focus.

[`android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:focusableInTouchMode):

> Boolean that controls whether
>   a view can take focus while in touch mode. If this is true for a view,
>   that view can gain focus when clicked on, and can keep focus if
>   another view is clicked on that doesn't have this attribute set to
>   true.

View needs to get focus to call Click listeners.

Comment: I removed all. Still not working. Please how can I solve it ?